# I have correct permissions, but can't access user interests through Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am trying to retrieve user interests through the Facebook Graph API, using PHP SDK.

I have all the correct permissions, but my API call doesn't return anything. Here is my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => APP_ID,
    'secret' => APP_SECRET,
));

$user_interests = $facebook->api('/'.$user_facebook_id.'/interests');
```

I get nothing. What am I missing?

edit: Actually, it returns this array:

```
$user_interests = { ["data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its works for me, (if user doesn't have any interests means the array will return nothing)

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => 'APP_ID','secret' => 'SECRET_ID', ));

$user_fb = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user_fb)
{   
  $user_interest = $facebook->api('/me/interests');   

  for($i =0; $i < sizeof($user_interest[data]); $i++) 
  {
    echo "Interest Name : ".$user_interest[data][$i]['name']."<br>";
    echo "Interest Category : ".$user_interest[data][$i]['category']."<br>";
    echo "Interest Id : ".$user_interest[data][$i]['id']."<br>";
    echo "Interest Created Time : ".$user_interest[data][$i]['created_time']."<br>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need "user_interests" permission and it will work fine